# A class inherited from a class with fixed data

Tags: c++, directx-9

I'm developing a GUI for directx in C++.
I've got a class for my controls:

```
class cControl;
```

a class for my windows:

```
class cWindow : public cControl
```

and what I want to do is write a class for a special kind of window (color picker).

```
class cColorPicker : public cWindow
```

The constructor of the colorpicker class calls only cControl functions.
To set things up in the gui routine for every window I use this code this:

```
for each( cWindow* pWindow in m_vWindows )
    // stuff
```

What I notice debugging is that position, width, height and every thing I set up in colorpicker constructor results null.

EDIT:
what I want to do is having a special window with a constructor that sets up (eg) width, height, etc, of the window.
Will this do the work?

```
cColorPicker::cColorPicker( int x, int y )
{
    cWindow::cWIndow( x, y, ... )
}
```

EDIT2: 
second problem:
I have to call a function from cWindow class (a function that adds a control to the window) but it seems to give problems too, and I think I have to do it inside of the constructor of cColorPicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should use [member initializer list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) to initialize base object with parameter

```
cColorPicker::cColorPicker(int x, int y)
: cWIndow( x, y, ... ), width(42),height(42) 
{
}
```

EDIT:
   If you want to add extra parameter to base constructor, should pass it from cColorPick constructor to its base:

```
cColorPicker::cColorPicker(int x, int y, cControl* pControl)
: cWIndow( x, y, pControl, ...), width(42),height(42) 
{
}

// edit or create a new cWindow constructor to accept CControl* parameter
cWIndow::cWIndow(int x, int y, cControl* pControl)
:width(x), height(y), m_vControls(pControl)
{
}
```

Comment: I have to call a cWindow:: function but it seems to give problems too, but for the pas problem that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You should initialize object in constructor, call cWindow::function in cWindow constructor to initialize cWidnow

Comment: look EDIT2 for the problem explaination

Comment: where is the control added to? does cWindow has a member to hold it, if yes,should do it in constructor

Comment: 'class cWindow ... {  ... vector<cControl*> m_vControls; void AddControl( cControl* pControl ); }' it adds it to m_vControls

Comment: you could call cColorPicker.AddControl() function to add cControl to m_vControls. derived object has access to base public functions

Comment: can't I call it in the constructor, can I?